# Javascript Syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I'm building a simple game to try to teach myself js/jQuery and can't get this part of my code to run. Firebug says there's a syntax error after the "endGame" function. If I remove the semicolon, Firebug just moves the error to the next line. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've looked through SO to see how other else if statements are formatted and couldn't spot the problem. Thanks in advance.

```
var cs = current_score,
ts = total_score;

function score(){
if($('.col_1 div .picked').hasClass('x'||'w')) {
    if($('.col_2 div .picked').hasClass('x'||'w')) {
        cs += 25;
        if($('.col_3 div .picked').hasClass('x'||'w')) {
            cs += 75;
            if($('.col_4 div .picked').hasClass('x'||'w')) {
                cs += 225;
                if($('.col_5 div .picked').hasClass('x'||'w')) {
                    cs += 675;
                    if($('.col_6 div .picked').hasClass('bonus_2')) {
                        cs += 2000;
                    }else if($('.col_6 div .picked').hasClass('bonus_5')) {
                        cs += 5000;
                    }else{} 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}else if($('.col_1 div .picked').hasClass('y'||'w')) {
    if($('.col_2 div .picked').hasClass('y'||'w')) {
        cs += 25;
        if($('.col_3 div .picked').hasClass('y'||'w')) {
            cs += 75;
            if($('.col_4 div .picked').hasClass('y'||'w')) {
                cs += 225;
                if($('.col_5 div .picked').hasClass('y'||'w')) {
                    cs += 675;
                    if($('.col_6 div .picked').hasClass('bonus_2')) {
                        cs += 2000;
                    }else if($('.col_6 div .picked').hasClass('bonus_5')) {
                        cs += 5000;
                    }else{} 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}else {}
function endGame();
};
```

Comment: What is this `function endGame();
};`???

Comment: Declaring function endgame inside function score?

Comment: Before posting here with syntax errors run your code through http://jshint.com/ or http://jslint.com

Comment: what are you trying to do with `.hasClass('y'||'w')`

Comment: @megawac -  Thank, I didn't know about jshint.

Comment: @Arun P Johny - I'm trying to check if the .picked elements match by comparing its other classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove function before your `endGame()` call and the semicolon at the end.
Then all syntax errors are resolved.

Comment: Thanks, mate. Got confused between declaring a function and calling it. I agree with all the comments stating there are other errors with the logic, but at least fixing the syntax lets me run the rest of the code to work the logic out.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `}` after your `}else {}`

That is your `function score(){` is not being closed

Answer (score 0):

```
function endGame();
};
```

Should probably be something more like

```
    function endGame() {

    }
};
```

If you put 'function' in front of some word, you're declaring a function. If you're not trying to declare a function but simply run a function that already exists elsewhere, just call it by `endGame();`.

Beyond that, you have a host of other errors.. you really need to simplify how you're starting out. This is not something I'd want to have to deal with :)